# Delegate error in table view cell

Tags: swift, delegates, segue, uitableview

i have error in delegate refer to line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

and the delegate between table view not exist

[github link](https://github.com/BusinessWallet/BW1.git)

> 2016-03-06 01:48:12.189 BusinessWallet[11069:1325173] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:6564
>   2016-03-06 01:48:12.402 BusinessWallet[11069:1325173] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107bdbe65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109953deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107bdbcca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>       3   Foundation                          0x00000001080244de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
>       4   UIKit                               0x000000010853ea8d -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 266
>       5   BusinessWallet                      0x0000000106f0fd61 _TFC14BusinessWallet14CategoriesView9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 113
>       6   BusinessWallet                      0x0000000106f0fe0f _TToFC14BusinessWallet14CategoriesView9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 79
>       7   UIKit                               0x0000000108551e43 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 766
>       8   UIKit                               0x0000000108551f7b -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
>       9   UIKit                               0x0000000108526a39 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2996
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000010855b01c -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000108541edc -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 224
>       12  UIKit                               0x00000001084af4a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
>       13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c06459a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
>       14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c058e70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
>       15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c058cee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
>       16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c04d475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
>       17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c07ac0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
>       18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c07b37c _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b07367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b072d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107afcf2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
>       22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107afc828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>       23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b8f1ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>       24  UIKit                               0x00000001083f8610 UIApplicationMain + 171
>       25  BusinessWallet                      0x0000000106f143ed main + 109
>       26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a45c92d start + 1
>       27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

```
class CategoriesView: UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var CheefsCell : UITableViewCell?
@IBOutlet weak var BeautyCell : UITableViewCell?
@IBOutlet weak var StudentServicesCell : UITableViewCell?
@IBOutlet weak var ArtAndDesigneCell : UITableViewCell?
@IBOutlet weak var StoreCell : UITableViewCell?
@IBOutlet weak var OthersCell : UITableViewCell?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 5

}
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
    // configure your cell here

    return cell
}
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier=="CheefsSegue") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! CheefsView}
        else  if (segue.identifier=="BeautySegue") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! BeautyView}
        else if (segue.identifier=="StudentServiceSegue") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! StudentServicesView}
        else  if (segue.identifier=="ArtAndDesigneSegue") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! ArtAndDesigneView}
        else  if (segue.identifier=="StoeSegue") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! StoreView}
        else  if (segue.identifier=="OthersSegue") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! OthersView}

    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    } }
```

Comment: This error has to do with **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath**, you need to set your cell name in interface builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

> reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CCell - must
>   register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype
>   cell in a storyboard'

In your storyboard, give your cell the "CCell" identifier.

[image]